# Remember position and size in a cookie

Tags: jquery-ui, cookies, draggable

I have no idea what is to do. Please help.

I have built a website with draggable scaleable items on a page. You can see what I've done here...
http://www.hagueandhague.co.uk/test/hagueandhague/httpdocs/index.html

It uses java script from...
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js

What I need the site to do is remember the position and scale of the items so that when visitors return to the site the items are where they left them.

I believe it is possible to store this information in a cookie, however I have no idea how to do that or make it work.

Any help would be great, but even better if it's in english/layman's.

Thanks in advance.

James.

Answer (score 1):

In "layman" terms, you want to use the Draggable plugin's `stop` callback to get the position of the element and save it to a cookie using the jQuery cookie plugin. Then when the user returns, read the cookie and re-position the elements.

```
$(".selector").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $.cookie("elementIDCookie", ui.position);
    }
});
```

To re-position the element when the user returns:

```
$(".select").css( { "left" : $.cookie("elementIDCookie").left, "top" : $.cookie("elementIDCookie").top });
```

More info:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I think that HTML5 local storage would be much more useful - the cookie size is very limited and it's worthless to send them all back to server every time - [see](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jStorage)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dragboard').draggable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                $.cookie('elementLeft', ui.position.left);
                $.cookie('elementTop', ui.position.top);
            }
        });
        $('.dragboard').css({left : parseInt($.cookie('elementLeft')), top : parseInt($.cookie('elementTop'))});
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work straight out of the box - #pick-right being the div to drag.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         if ($.cookie("rcpos") != undefined) {
             var unwrapped = window.JSON.parse($.cookie("rcpos"));
             var left = window.JSON.parse($.cookie("rcpos")).left;
             var top = window.JSON.parse($.cookie("rcpos")).top;
             $("#pick-right").css("left", left + "px");
             $("#pick-right").css("top", top + "px");
         }
     });

     $(function () {
         $("#pick-right").draggable({ stop: function (event, ui) {
             $.cookie("rcpos", window.JSON.stringify(ui.position));
         }
         });
     });
```